# Cannot simulate the write() system call in C

Tags: c

I have written the following code to simulate the `write()` system call in `C`.
The program executes without errors, but the new content is not written to `myfile`.

What is the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    int fd;
    int i = 1;
    char *sep = "";

    if(ac < 1)
    {
        printf("Insuff arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if((fd = open("myfile", 0660)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(i<ac)
    {
        write(fd, av[i], strlen(av[i]));
        write(fd, sep, strlen(sep));
        i++;
    }
    close (fd);
}
```

Comment: Always *always* **always** check for errors!

Comment: Cannot find any errors. Only warnings. Please help.

Comment: What does the `write` calls return?

Comment: What's the printf output? i.e. what is your value of ac. If < 2 then on first glance there will be no output.

Comment: You are calling `write`, not simulating it.

Comment: By the way, `ac` will *never* be less than one.

Comment: @nouney Only call `perror` if e.g. `write` fails. Checking `errno` when the call succeeded is undefined.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yep that's right, I'm a bit tired ;)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Are you sure? `execl("a.out", (char *)0);`

Comment: @R.. Okay, I amend my statement to say that `ac` will never be less than one, unless you purposefully call `exec*` with zero arguments, which in normal cases will be just about never.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Where it matters is when your program might be run by a potentially malicious caller, e.g. if it's suid. For example it would be bad if the `passwd` utility happened to access `argv[0]` while holding a dotlock-style lock on the `/etc/shadow` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should check the return value of write and see what's going on with perror (for exemple),

anyway you are not calling open in the correct way

try

```
  if ((fd=open("myfile", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0660))==-1)
    {
      printf("Cannot open file");
      exit(1);
    }
  while(i<ac)
    {
      write(fd,av[i],strlen(av[i])); //check the return value of write
      write(fd,sep,strlen(sep));
      perror("write");
      i++;
    }
  close (fd);
```

and include unistd.h fcntl.h

Comment: What does 0660 denote anyway?

Comment: Specifies the permissions to use in case a new file is created. This argument must be supplied when O_CREAT is specified in flags; if O_CREAT is not specified, then mode is ignored. You should take a look at http://linux.die.net/man/2/open

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify mode(read or write) of the open when you are opening a file. In your open call you didn't specify any mode and you are giving file permission flags. For more information refer manual page of open system call.

You can try this in open call

```
fd=open("myfile", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0660);
```

check return value of your write call, it is failing because you didn't specify any mode and you are trying to write data in to that file.